# What's the exact purpose of the getData() function in ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using [ngTable](http://ng-table.com/#/) in a big project. What is the exact purpose of the getData function sent in the table params ?

```
vm.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
```

I guess that `data` is an array of objects in my controller, and that data are not found into my DOM like dataTables does.
I have also seen a `$data`object that make confusion.

Bonus : Why is this `slice()` stuff needed ?

Comment: `slice` is here for pagination.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `getData` method is to retrieve the data and pass it to ngTable for rendering. It is supposed to fetch/load rows that should be displayed on the current page, according to selected filters, sorting, etc (you use `params` object for this).

When the data is loaded, say with ajax request you are supposed to resolve promise object passed into getData function with prepared array of rows.

In the example above `data` array is a local variable so there is no need to issue ajax request to load it (this is just for demo), so you can simply pass it to promise. Also additional slicing is performed in order to simulate paging, like if it came from the server already sliced.

Usually `getData` would be used something like this:

```
getData: function ($defer, params) {
    $http.get('/accounts/', {params: {page: params.page()}}).then(function(response) {
        $defer.resolve(response.data);
    });
}
```